# Fresh 16.04 install. Black screen on reboot but fine if started from scratch

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have just done a fresh install on an HP Pavillion G6 Notebook. This has an  AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 and Graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0). It works fine on initial boot but has a black screen on reboot. I can fix this with a hard shutdown (holding down power key) and restarting from there. I tried changing the grub config by adding GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep as shown in another similar post, but this didn't help. Has anyone got any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue on lenovo y560 with Radeon HD 5730. I upgrade the kernel to 4.5.2 and worked fine for a week. Yesterday there was an update and now I have the same problem.

Comment: I went to 14.04 and this fixed it.